# Node.js fails: node:internal/errors:465

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, yarnpkg

We got this error, no clue why, other machines can run Next.js app, have same yarn, nodejs versions.

```
csababolyai@EU-C02G409AML85 TikexPortal % yarn dev
yarn run v1.22.18
$ next build
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
npx browserslist@latest --update-db
node:internal/errors:465
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/parser' is not defined by "exports" in /Users/csababolyai/Personal/TikexPortal/node_modules/next/node_modules/postcss/package.json
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
    at throwExportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:440:9)
    at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:719:3)
    at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:482:36)
```

Comment: Are you absolutely, positively sure you're running the Node version you think you are? What does `node --version` say (instead of `next build`)?